# Which part of the communication is encrypted under a HTTPs communication?

Tags: https

When my browser sends a request under a HTTPs communication which parts of the request are encrypted?

- URL (I suppose not)
- GET params (I suppose not)
- POST/PUT params
- Cookies
- Headers
- ...
- The response of the server

I'm concern about this because I was implementing an API where there was private data into the URL with the hope of it to be protected by a HTTPs communication, but I'm afraid the URL it self is not encrypted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the secure channel is stablished, all the HTTP info is encrypted, URL, get/post params, cookies and headers. And of course the response from the server.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [HTTP Secure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure#Network_layers), the whole HTTP message is sent through a SSL connection to the server, so method, url (including query parameters), headers, body, etc. is encrypted.